# YouTube Data API で著作権情報を取得する方法

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

YouTube Data API使って管理画面に出る著作権情報（侵害しているとか、一部の国でブロックとか出るやつ）
を取得しようとしています。以下のページを参考に応答を確認していますが、著作権侵害扱い動画にもかかわらずfalseで返ってきてしまいます。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084922/how-can-i-possibly-retrieve-copyright-issue-from-youtube-api

著作権侵害動画（例）
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HB_mZsIarpc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juCb9LfWEBo

何をどうすればいいのでしょうか？ご指南いただけると助かります。よろしくお願いします。

ちなみにサンプルコードは以下のとおりです。

```
const CLIENT_ID = '*****';
const CLIENT_SECRET = '*****';
const API_KEY = '*****';
const REFRESH_TOKEN = '*****';

public function getVideo($videoId)
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(self::CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(self::CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setDeveloperKey(self::API_KEY);
    $client->refreshToken(self::REFRESH_TOKEN);
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    $listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('contentDetails',
            array('id' => $videoId));
    if (!empty($listResponse)) {
        var_dump($listResponse[0]['contentDetails']);
    }
}
```

【1/6追記】
いくつかの動画でテストしてみましたが、lisencedContent に関してはtrueになるものと
falseになるもので分かれるようです。
広告が出るものに関して全て検知する属性がわかると助かります。
どうかよろしくお願いします。

広告無しtrue
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jN8j9ZlQNxY

広告ありtrue
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UT6i8DpJSt8

広告無しfalse
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EYVT81JMVI

広告ありfalse
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZEDqCmdejU

Comment: 可能であれば問題が起きているコードを載せてください。回答者の助けになります。

Comment: 追記します！少々お待ちください。

Answer (score 1):

[`licensedContent`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.licensedContent) は、**ライセンスされているかどうか** なので、下記の状況は"ライセンスされていない" (著作権侵害?) なのではないでしょうか。

```
$listResponse[0]['contentDetails']['licensedContent'] === FALSE
```

また、"一部の国でブロック" については別プロパティの [`regionRestriction`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction) に情報があるようです。

Comment: 遅くなってすみません。ちょっと確認します。月曜になりますがまたご連絡いたします！ご回答有難うございます。

Comment: 再度確認したのですが、下記の特に広告の出ない
（著作権侵害をしていない）動画で上記API取得してもすべてFalseで返って来るようです。
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=jbYcAm8yoMY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=s4WPDxevYCY
こちらの想定としては著作権侵害（広告が出る）動画のみ
Trueになるというパラメータがあればという感じなのですが
いかがでしょうか？
何度もすみません。

Comment: 広告が表示される動画は、lisencedContent が true になるかと思いますが、如何でしょう？

Comment: 遅くなりましたが、テストいたしました。結果lisencedContent が trueになるものとfalseのものとに分かれることが判明しました。
元の質問表記を修正しましたのでご確認よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 色々見てみましたが、 広告が表示される / されない の別を API で取るのは難しそうですね。（広告付動画を弾くことが可能になるので当然かもしれません。） このあたりとか、ご参考になれば → https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2475463?hl=ja

Comment: ありがとうございます！確かにそうですね。参考情報のパターンも納得です。お手数おかけいたしました。